# MFMessageComposeViewController for text messaging is not working in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, sms

In my app I am using MFMessageComposeViewController for sending text messages. It worked fine in iPhone but I am unable to send message in iPad. I any other way to send SMS from iPad aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll only work on iPad if you have iMessage set up.

Call `[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]` before you try to send a text to make sure the device is capable of sending texts.